# Scale factor for xxhdpi android?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

according to http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

The following scale factors are mentioned

xhdpi: 2.0
hdpi: 1.5
mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
ldpi: 0.75

I was wondering what the scale factor would be for xxhdpi?

Comment: Does it even support xxhdpi? Not like Google to miss something out of the docs

Comment: @musefan , android sdk creates a folder automatically since the start of this year atleast , called drawable-xxhdpi . Also S4 , HTC ONE , and Xperia Z are xxhdpi . I have seen them take resources from the xxhdpi bucket . they are way above the xhdpi (240) level

Comment: see my answer [here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/how-to-design-any-screen-size-and-density-in-androidmulti-screen-for-mobiles/36821546#36821546)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

In [android.util.DisplayMetrics](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/DisplayMetrics.java), you can see that scaling factor is **0.00625**:

```
/**
 * Scaling factor to convert a density in DPI units to the density scale.
 * @hide
 */
public static final float DENSITY_DEFAULT_SCALE = 1.0f / DENSITY_DEFAULT;
```

Where as [DENSITY_DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_DEFAULT) is 160 --> scaling factor = 1.0f / 160 = 0.00625.

```
sizeScale = DENSITY_DEFAULT_SCALE * DENSITY_DPI
```

From this:

- **ldpi** = 0.00625 * [120](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_LOW) -> **0.75**
- **mdpi** = 0.00625 * [160](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_MEDIUM) -> **1.0**
- **hdpi** = 0.00625 * [240](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_HIGH) -> **1.5**
- **xhdpi** = 0.00625 * [320](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XHIGH) -> **2.0**
- **xxhdpi** = 0.00625 * [480](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH) -> **3.0**
- **xxxhdpi** = 0.00625 * [640](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXXHIGH) -> **4.0**

Not exactly a rocket science, but hope this will be useful for someone :)

Comment: and tvdpi -> 1.3312501 (for example: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8)

Comment: I wonder if this is still true; the Google Device Metrics site lists both 3.5 and 4.0 scaling for xxxhdpi: https://design.google.com/devices/. I'm not sure how to resolve that inconsistency...

Comment: @lilbyrdie: it does still hold. See the comment for `DENSITY_560` in `android.util.DisplayMetrics`

Comment: @ozbek: So even though the devices might be labelled xxxhdpi, internally they aren't? That also implies _all_ graphics are scaled for them? That doesn't sound very efficient. I also see that there are _four_ other intermediate densities... In any case, thanks for the info. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: xxxhdpi is only used for launcher icons anyway.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#xxxhdpi-note

Comment: @the_new_mr well, Google does not seem to follow that guideline themselves though. Almost all of their apps have non-launcher-icon images under xxxhdpi folders.

Comment: @ozbek Really?  That's insane.  Perhaps we shouldn't be surprised.  It's buried so deep in the documentation that even the Google developers themselves probably don't know it :)

Comment: @the_new_mr - that makes no sense, nor is it what docs say anywhere that I've seen [though perhaps the docs hadn't been updated properly for xxxhdpi, when you wrote your answer!]. xxxhdpi is for *all* resources, on a device that says it is 640 dpi.

Comment: @ozbek - FWIW, I found the use of `0.00625 *` in your list of densities confusing. Wouldn't it be simpler to do `nnn / 160`?  Then it would be immediately obvious why "320 / 160" -> "2.0". :)

Comment: @lilbyrdie - ".. all graphics are scaled for them?". Not necessarily. The declared density is a *logical* density. For example, if a phone's actual, physical density was 163 dpi, it would be terrible to have to scale all images to that exact, true, density. Result would look bad. Instead, a phone picks a nice, round, number. Its as if the phone was physically slightly larger, or slightly smaller, such that the density becomes a simple round number. This means that if you draw a "1 inch" square on different phones, you'll find its size varies on each model. But images will be clean.

Comment: BTW, the newer "in-between" display densities are: 420dpi / 160 -> "2.625" multiplier, and 560dpi / 160 -> "3.5" multiplier.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at [Metrics and Grids](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) you'll see that xxhdpi is 480 dpi which is 3 times that of the baseline (mdpi @ 1.0). In other words the scale factor for xxhdpi is 3.0