# How to calculate the pixel density (dp) of a device?

Tags: android, resolution, density-independent-pixel

What is the independent pixel density for a Galaxy s4?

I need it so I can have a qualifier `sw???dp` for that phone.

It would be great if you could explain how to calculate it.

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/multi-screen-for-mobiles-in-android/36821546#36821546)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can find how to calculate `sw???dp` for every device you want.

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061)

I think that instead of 96 x 5' (screen size) you should use these qualifiers: http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html (160, 240, 320, 480). In this case of Galaxy S4, you get the good result, but if you try for example with a Nexus4 (4,7 ') you will get `sw~272` instead of `380` as it should, and as happens in practice. This is the value you should use in your formula and you will get the right result.

**OR**

run this snippet code: (API 13+)

> int sw = getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp;

Answer (score 16):

Nobody answered the question:
S4: Resolution  1080 x 1920 pixels (~441 ppi pixel density) per gsmarena
formula:  px = dp * (dpi / 160) from Google's article on "Supporting multiple screens".
Therefore: dp = px / (dpi / 160). So, shortest width (sw) = 1080/(441/160) = **391**

As also stated here: [Use size and density-specific resources problems in Android app design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468872/use-size-and-density-specific-resources-problems-in-android-app-design)

Comment: Thank you! For actually answering the question instead of just providing maths equations!

Answer (score 5):

Galaxy s4 has a density of about ~441ppi i.e so the `scale factor` will come around 441/160=2.75. which is much higher than `hdpi(1.5)` or `xhdpi (2.0)`.Put your fonts xml in 
`values-xxhdpi` folder.

You can also have a look here   [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655194/scale-factor-for-xxhdpi-android) for any further queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can always find it in gsmarena.

For other unknown phones here's the formula for calculating the dpi:

```
dpi = ( square_root ( horizontal_pixels ^ 2 + vertical_pixels ^ 2 )) / ( screen_size )
```

In the case of galaxy s4:

- horizontal pixels = 1080
- vertical pixels = 1920
- screen size = 5.0

Then

```
dpi = ( square_root ( 1080 ^ 2 + 1920 ^ 2 )) /  5.0

dpi = ( square_root ( 1166400 + 3686400 )) /  5.0

dpi = ( square_root ( 4852800 )) /  5.0

dpi = ( 2202.91 ) /  5.0

dpi = 440.5

dpi = 441 dpi
```