# how to scale image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scale

this is my code i want to scale my drawable image and set on image view please help me 
here in my code i want to scale **bitmap1** please check my code

```
         protected Bitmap murge() 
         { 
        Murge_Bitmap = null;
        Murge_Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(Murge_Bitmap);
        Resources res = getResources(); 
        bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sample_pic); 
        Bitmap bitmap2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 600, 600, true);

        Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap2);
         //   c.drawBitmap(Murge_Bitmap, 500,500, null);
        drawable1.setBounds(200, 200, 400, 400);
        drawable2.setBounds(200, 240, 400, 400);
        drawable1.draw(c);
        drawable2.draw(c);


        return Murge_Bitmap;
             }
```

Comment: please visit https://github.com/matabii/scale-imageview-android

Comment: Go to official [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: this is example is not running it's terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:
Decode the resource and pass it to this function with scalingfactor

```
public static Bitmap ScaleBitmap(Bitmap bm, float scalingFactor) {
    int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() * scalingFactor);
    int scaleWidth = (int) (bm.getWidth() * scalingFactor);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
}
```

for scaling factor refer to this
[Scale factor for xxhdpi android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655194/scale-factor-for-xxhdpi-android)

Comment: i want to scale manually by user in my application by touch event please give me source code for touchevent

Comment: scale manually?? you mean to say corp image? or let the user select the scaling factor, height and weight ??

Comment: not crop, resize by user large and small according their requirement

Comment: you can use seekbar in android and imageview, get the value form the seekbar and pass it to scaleBitmap function. http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-seekbar-example.html#.UvorxPmSySo