# Having layout problems with Samsung galaxy Note 3

Tags: android, android-layout

Through testing and developing a simple app, I've seen that the Note 3 doesn't have a layout folder, I've looked and the largest layout folder is *layout-xlarge*, which supports *xhdpi* devices(~320dpi). Whereas the Note 3 has a density of ~386dpi, and it doesn't have a way of using it's own layout folder because one doesn't exist, so it ends up using the default layout folder. [android layout source](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

This is causing problems with animations, they look choppy and button presses are even being affected by it while the animation is running.

Is there any way of defining a layout folder for devices with a higher dpi than xhdpi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scale factor for xxhdpi android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655194/scale-factor-for-xxhdpi-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create folder **layout-xhdpi** with resources what you needed in it. For more details see ["Best Practices 4. Use size and density-specific resources"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) on Android Developers.