# How to hide partially visible views in Android layout xml without code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout, android-appwidget

**Please read the question fully before answering!**

Suppose I have two views:

1. `first` (yellow) in the bottom
2. `second` (cyan) filling the rest of the view above `first`

*The size of the parent view is dynamic.*

**How can I achieve the below Expected column UI when the parent height is dynamically set to the values in the first column?** Notice how the partially visible view is just hidden instead of cropped.

[image: What I want to achieve]

## Constraints

- Any **code is not a possibility**, I know it's possible to solve the problem with:
  `second.setVisibility(second.getHeight() < SECONDS_PREFERRED_SIZE? GONE : VISIBLE)`
  but I don't have access to `getHeight()` so the solution must be bare xml.
  It can be relaxed to code only writing UI state via `RemoteViews`.
- Based on the above **no custom views** are allowed, **no**t even **libraries**, just **basic layout managers**:
  `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `GridLayout`
  or as a last resort one of the advanced ones:
  `ViewFlipper`, `ListView`, `GridView`, `StackView` or `AdapterViewFlipper`
- The `layout_width` and `layout_height` is **dynamic**
  In the example I fixed it so it's easy to try out different variations. The above image is the `layout_height` changed to the displayed value simulating the possibilities I want to handle.
- I used `TextView`, but it should be generally applicable to any `View`
- Observant people may have noticed that the above constrains the solution to [Home screen **app widgets** with `RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

## Tries

I tried implementing with `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`, but they both behave as the Actual column on the picture.

### RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="64dp" (actually fill_parent, but fix it for sake of simplicity)
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" (first column on picture)
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#666"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#8ff0"
        android:text="First"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/first"
        android:background="#80ff"
        android:text="Second"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="64dp" (actually fill_parent, but fix it for sake of simplicity)
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" (first column on picture)
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#666"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#80ff"
        android:text="Second"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#8ff0"
        android:text="First"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "I don't have access to getHeight()" why?

Comment: @mmlooloo: because there are no `View` getters on [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html). There's no feedback from the remote process (widget host), it's one way, this why I'm asking layout xml only.

Comment: Its sixteen plus -24 for a padding of 8 on the top edge.

Comment: @danny117 I'm not sure I understand, can you please test it by copying one of my tries. Then do your suggested changes and play around by changing `layout_height="16dp"` to the values on the image to compare the visuals.

Comment: It's obvious there is padding on the top edge how that padding disappears?  I'm interested in the answer to this puzzle too.

Comment: Does android:minHeight="[height of 'first' or 'second']" work? I'm not sure if it works with text views.

Comment: @Lukos not really. Firstly "height of 'second'" is dynamic so can't really use that. As I tried use `minHeight`, it only works if parent is `wrap_content` - it forces the view to be minimum the given value - but the parent is `fill_parent` here, and grandparent has a fixed size which cannot expand under any circumstances, and makes `fill_parent` kind of fixed as well. If you can make it work somehow with some example, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: What if you wrapped those views in LinearLayouts and set min height on them? 

I haven't tested this, but that way may be able to wrap your dynamic content in a container and also force it to have a minimum height.

Comment: @Lukos please copy the one of the xmls and set height to 24dp, then modify contents to achieve what's on the picture, then change it to 8dp and check if it works that way as well.

Comment: Do you have access to the height of the body? i mean the height of the widget that is calling you?

Comment: @ConductedClever not really, see the current answer, even if I do this snippet is just about 5th of the full layout, so hand-calculation may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a RemoteViews/widget, try using multiple layout files. Extend [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) and override the [`onAppWidgetOptionsChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) method. In this function you'll want to do the following:

```
Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);
int minHeight = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
```

Then case on minHeight to determine which layout is most appropriate to inflate. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) is incredibly useful when making widgets.

Comment: Multiple layout files is a great idea for this type of problem.

Comment: I'm targeting API 10, that method is API 16. Even if I were to use it for newer versions, I think I wasn't able to get the right cell size. I know Samsung Galaxy S4 has `84dp x 105dp` widget cells, but I couldn't get near that number. I think it was giving me the `minHeight` I specified on `<appwidget-provider>`. I'll give those MIN/MAX another try though and report back.

Comment: I checked again (all values are `dp`): "*onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(appWidgetID, Bundle[{appWidgetMaxHeight=89, appWidgetCategory=1, appWidgetMaxWidth=89, appWidgetMinHeight=68, appWidgetMinWidth=68}])*". `68x68`—`89x89` is really far from `84x105`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing with widgets. The sizes they give you are approximate and they aren't even stable from device to device or launcher to launcher.

Answer (score 1):

While the [`OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN/MAX_WIDTH/HEIGHT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT) doesn't really report the real values, I found a way around it. *Note that this doesn't really solve the problem at hand, but is a rather convoluted workaround.*

#### Source of the idea

```
Normal update from the widget host
26061-26061/net.twisterrob.app.debug V/TAG﹕ onReceive(Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE flg=0x10000010 cmp=net.twisterrob.app.debug/net.twisterrob.app.AppWidgetProvider (has extras) } (Bundle[{appWidgetIds=[I@42b14090}]))  
26061-26061/net.twisterrob.app.debug V/TAG﹕ onUpdate([483])  

User tap with setOnClickPendingIntent
26061-26061/net.twisterrob.app.debug V/TAG﹕ onReceive(Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE flg=0x10000010 cmp=net.twisterrob.app.debug/net.twisterrob.app.AppWidgetProvider bnds=[281,756][533,1071] (has extras) } (Bundle[{appWidgetIds=[I@42b14090}]))  
26061-26061/net.twisterrob.app.debug V/TAG﹕ onUpdate([483])
```

#### Investigation

When [`RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) broadcasts the tap by the user, it'll put [the bounds of the view in the `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSourceBounds()). As you can see in `bnds=[281,756][533,1071]` the views is `533-281=252` wide and `1071-756=315` tall, these are pixels and the Galaxy S4 is an [XXHDPI (3x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655194/scale-factor-for-xxhdpi-android) device, so `252x315 / 3 = 84x105` which is exactly what my empirical observation was about the widget cell size.

The bounds given depends on the `viewId` given to `setOnClickPendingIntent`, so to get the cell size, one will need to attach the pending intent on root view in the layout. My widget has a "tap-to-refresh" listener which I can safely attach to the root layout. There are other views which do have `PendingIntent`s, but those cover the root layout so their intent will be broadcast, just like regular `onClickListener`s.

#### Solution

Now, this means that we know the exact cell size, based on this it may be possible to calculate some views' size by hand (for simpler layouts). Essentially we have way to get **`root.getHeight()`**, we can "hardcode" the size of `first` into a `R.dimen.firstHeight`, and from this we can calculate whether to show `first`, `second` or none.

Or, make use of these bounds just like @AndrewOrobator suggested: inflate a layout appropriate for the size.

#### Requires user interaction

The only problem that this requires user interaction at least once. When the widget host sends the update there are no bounds, so the user must tap a view so we have the size. I would work around this, by forcing the user to tap on the view once (just after they installed the widget to home):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        for (int appWidgetId : getAppWidgetIds(intent)) {
            Rect storedBounds = getSizeFromPreferences(appWidgetId);
            Rect sourceBounds = intent.getSourceBounds();
            if (storedBounds == null && sourceBounds != null) {
                // no stored size, but we just received one, save it
                setSizeToPreferences(appWidgetId, sourceBounds);
                storedBounds = sourceBounds;
            }
            if (storedBounds == null) {
                // we didn't have a stored size, neither received one
                // force the user to interact with the widget once so we have a size
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_tap_to_refresh);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.root, createRefresh(context, appWidgetId));
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            } else {
                // update as usual, and use the bounds from getSizeFromPreferences(appWidgetId)
                onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), new int[] {appWidgetId});
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
private @NonNull int[] getAppWidgetIds(Intent intent) {
    int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
    if (appWidgetIds == null) {
        appWidgetIds = new int[0];
    }
    return appWidgetIds;
}
private @NonNull PendingIntent createRefresh(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetId);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```