# Working with coordinates in android for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-canvas

In an application, let suppose we have an image of a car onto which we have mark a damage point. We can mark this point anywhere of the image as shown below.

[image: Image 1:]

Suppose we have marked this point on a device of screen size “5 inches” and then we calculated the coordinates of this point and sent it to the server.
Now the user is using another device of screen size “8 inches”. User wants to see those marked points in his new device. But he is not able to see the appropriate position of the points after fetching the actual value from the server.

[image: Image 2:]

Comment: instead of a coordinates just upload the whole image with damage point to your server.

Comment: @RahulSharma sending image to the server is not an actual solution.

Comment: You can always calculate the coordinates as a proportion of the screen size in both the x and y directions. These proportions can be uploaded to the server in the form of a simple array.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks for your response. Can you give me an example of calculating the coordinates as a proportion of the screen size in both the x and y directions.

Answer (score 3):

I think the coordinates depend on the device's screen dpi. Assume your server always store the coordinates in mdpi. Then you should get the correct coordinates at device at different dpi like this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

float screenAdjust = (float) dm.densityDpi / 160f;


int x = (int) (x_value_from_server) * screenAdjust);
int y = (int) (y_value_from_server) * screenAdjust);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you let me know what is 160f here ?

Comment: 160f is the dpi of mdpi screen

Comment: I am using the concept you illustrated before. Can you please let me know how to save the coordinates in xxhdpi and then fetch it in mdpi. Is there any way to find it ?.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655194/scale-factor-for-xxhdpi-android , xxhdpi is 480. Therefore, convert coordinates from xxhdpi to mdpi is: (x/480f) * 160f.

Comment: Wow this works perfectly thanks for sharing this code

Answer (score 0):

Get the height and width of the screen

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Then calculate the coordinates of the image, I assume you are currently doing this in the form of an [x,y] `array`

Then simply find the ratio across all screen sizes by doing:

```
float x_ratio = coordinatesArray[0]/width
float y_ratio = coordinatesArray[1]/height
```

This will result in something along the lines of `0.25` and `0.34` (or something like that depending on the screen size)

You then simply create an array including these two floats and pass this along to the server.