# Android how to convert pixels from UI to dp in xml?

Tags: android, xml, dpi

My UX designer has given me a specs sheet of a 1440x2560px(QHD) screen. I will have to support all sizes from mdpi to xxhdpi.

I have gone through several px to dp converters but they tell only on how to convert px to dp for a specific dpi.

I have gone through the google example at https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html but that concentrates more on the layouts.

My question is, for x pixels given in the specs sheet (QHD), how do I map it to the dp of different dpi screens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scale factor for xxhdpi android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655194/scale-factor-for-xxhdpi-android)

Answer (score 0):

So according to me it goes like this.

I get my designs in xxhdpi which is also called 3x or we can say like 48px is equal to 16dp.

For your problem you are getting the designs in xxxhdpi so it is a 4x scaling that is 64px will convert to 16dp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped! We are dividing by 4, and adding the dp in the default dimens file. We have tested this across devices and the UI looks intact (except for ldpi) . If this is the case, why are there different dimes files available (mdpi, xdpi, xxdpi and so on)