# Exception: dalvikvm-heap(1099): Out of memory

Tags: android, android-activity, out-of-memory

I have problem I do not understand. When I reach the following code snippet

```
public class MatchViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("OnCreate in MatchViewActivity","1");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_view); <--- Crash occurrs here
        Log.d("","2");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
```

I get the following error in the simulator, always:

```
10-07 18:41:39.012: E/dalvikvm-heap(1099): Out of memory on a 3686416-byte allocation.
```

Some lines further down in the logcat I can find:

```
 10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.matchView.MatchViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.example.matchView.MatchViewActivity.onCreate(MatchViewActivity.java:25)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     ... 11 more
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     ... 23 more
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
10-07 18:41:39.452: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     ... 26 more
10-07 18:46:39.632: I/Process(1099): Sending signal. PID: 1099 SIG: 9
```

I checked that "activity_match_view" does exist. What is happening here?

The corresponding layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/matchView_ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your `res/layout/activity_match_view.xml`? Also, please post the LogCat data further down. There should be `Caused by:` and then some more error data.

Comment: I added the stuff you requested

Comment: Ok, now just post `res/drawable/main_background.xml`. Or, if it is ridiculously big the program crashes because the file fills the memory.

Comment: I cannot find a file called "res/drawable/main_background.xml" I only got folders that contain png files

Comment: `res/drawable-somethingdpi/main_background.xml`?

Comment: No xml files are in there

Comment: Did you check all folders starting with `res/drawable`? Or wait a sec, I might have forgotten. Is there `main_background.png` or some other image file with that name?

Comment: Can you find _any file_ that has `main_background` in then name in your project? If not I have no idea from where your drawable is coming from.

Comment: Yes, I got a png file in "res/drawable-mdpi" but not an xml file

Comment: OK, we found it. How big is it (in bytes **and** pixels)?

Comment: The graphic is just 190kbyte large. So I don't think that this is too large...the pixel size is 1280x720.

Comment: I found the cause (and the solution). See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445635/galaxy-s4-and-maybe-all-hd-phones-out-of-memory-error-inflating-layout

Answer (score 3):

The error is because the bitmap that the OS is trying to create for your background is possibly way too huge, hence it runs out of resources, also make sure the memory delegated for the emulator has a decent value, other way it might run out of memory easily.

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so because this activity uses the same background image as the activity before

Comment: yes, my point..., maybe the bitmap is too big, do this. Remove your background bmp, and change it for a single color and see what happens...

Comment: Yes, you're right. When the background image is removed from the xml it does not crash. So it is definitly due to the graphic. Additionally I extended the available RAM for the virtual device. Now it works. However the graphic is just 190kbyte.

Comment: Yes, there's a dark side of android :P regarding that, it doesn't matter if the image size is 1KB, android internally takes the memory of width * height * 4Bytes of the image in order to use it, you can actually notice using the DDMS "heap tracker" that a huge Image can easily take couple of MBs even when stored is couple of KBs, If this answer was helpful i would appreciate if you either +1 or mark it as correct...Regards!

Answer (score 0):

How big is your @drawable/main_background
It could be to big to load. Every Bitmap is in your memory so please provide small pictures

Answer (score 0):

Use .jpeg/.jpg format for background images instead of .png images because on recreation of resources in android .png takes more heap memory as compare to .jpeg/.jpg images.