# Android Layout OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory, bitmap

When loading an XML layout with a lot of ImageViews, I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryError`. Unlike most people who seem to be reporting this error, my layout just loads ImageViews directly from the Drawable folder by putting this XML attribute on each ImageView (of which there are about 50 in the layout):

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

Then, I load the layout all at once in the Activity's call to OnCreate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
}
```

Even following some common tricks (namely setting LargeHeap to true and reducing the size of the image), I still can't avoid this error. I can only assume that it's a result of the combination of the image being a few KB and it being loaded into about 50 ImageViews.

I can't reduce the size of the image any further and I can't reduce the number of ImageViews it's loaded into. Because I'm loading directly from the Drawable folder, it also doesn't seem like the tips in Android's guide to [displaying bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) or a third-party image-loading tool like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) are very likely to help.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: lots of images .thats why

Comment: I just wonder how big your xml is. Why you need to show all images will full size in 1 screen? Why dont you load only scaled image first?

Comment: are you sure you are putting the images in the correct density folders?

Answer (score 0):

### OutOfMemoryError

> Thrown when a request for memory is made that can not be satisfied
>   using the available platform resources. Such a request may be made by
>   both the running application or by an internal function of the VM.

You are dealing with large bitmaps and loading all of them at run time. You have to deal very **`carefully with large bitmaps by loading the size`** that you need not the whole bitmap at once and then **`do scaling`**.

Please read this **[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError – How to solve OutOfMemoryError](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-how-to-solve-outofmemoryerror/)**

> [galaxy s4 and maybe all HD phones? out of memory error inflating layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445635/galaxy-s4-and-maybe-all-hd-phones-out-of-memory-error-inflating-layout)